# What is the best way to export xml documents to local in markLogic?

Tags: marklogic, marklogic-8

I have 4 million xml docs in MarkLogic DB. I need to store all the XMLS in local folder.

What is the best and fast way to do so?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use [CORB](https://github.com/marklogic-community/corb2/) to transform and export the documents to files on the filesystem by configuring to apply a process module to transform the documents and use `PROCESS-TASK=com.marklogic.developer.corb.ExportToFileTask` to will write each of the documents to a file on the filesystem in the configured `EXPORT-FILE-DIR`.

Example properties for such a CORB job:

```
XCC-CONNECTION-URI=xcc://user:password@localhost:8202/   
THREAD-COUNT=10   
URIS-MODULE=select-documents.xqy|ADHOC
PROCESS-MODULE=transform-document.xqy|ADHOC
PROCESS-TASK=com.marklogic.developer.corb.ExportToFileTask   
EXPORT-FILE-DIR=/local/path/to/export/
```

Answer (score 6):

Your best bet would be the [MarkLogic Content Pump's Export feature](https://docs.marklogic.com/guide/mlcp/export)

```
mlcp.sh export -host YOURHOST -port YOURPORT -username USER -password PASS -mode local -output_file_path /location/to/local/folder
```

Please see the docs for additional examples and further information.

Comment: You could consider blending in an extra `-compress` which will make MLCP create zip files with batches of files, rather than individual files. Alternatively, you could use `-output_type archive` to create zips including meta-information like collections and permissions.

Comment: If you are using latest MLCP, you can also hit port 8000, and use `-database NAMEOFDATABASE` to target a specific documents database to export. Might save the trouble of creating an extra app-server to access it.

Comment: Thanks, Tamas. One more quest. Is it possible to transform the XML while exporting? In my case, While exporting I have to change the text of one element in each XML.

Comment: It would be nice if you use the transform options at export, but it only works on import and copy. It does accept a `-redaction` option which allows applying a set of redaction rules that could manipulate the text of an element.